# Creating concatenated results tables

Tags: sqlite, group-by, sum, union

I have table A like:

[image]

I have table B like:

[image]

I want a result table that concatenates columns and merges rows where necessary, something like:
[image]

I tried using Union but it didn't give me exactly what I wanted. Is there any other efficient way to achieve the result.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the tables in textual form. And please post the query that you've tried.

Comment: Share scripts for create table and insert data. Image will not work.

Comment: Sqlite and mysql are two different products. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easily solved if SQLite supported a `FULL` join, but it doesn't.

First use `UNION ALL` to create a resultset containing all the rows of the 2 tables with additional columns to cover both fruits and vegetables and then aggregate, so that in the case such as `'tomato'` you will have only 1 row:

```
SELECT Fruit_Veggie, 
       SUM(Count_Fruit) Count_Fruit,
       SUM(percent_fruit) percent_fruit,
       SUM(Count_Veggie) Count_Veggie,
       SUM(percent_Veggie ) percent_Veggie 
FROM (
  SELECT Fruit Fruit_Veggie, count Count_Fruit, percent percent_fruit, 0 Count_Veggie, 0 percent_Veggie 
  FROM TableA
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Veggies, 0, 0, count, percent
  FROM TableB
)
GROUP BY Fruit_Veggie
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a full join or a distinct union. You know this because you have one row for Tomato, which contains values from both tables. That will give you null values, which you'll turn into 0 (zeros) using coalesce. Is this homework?

Comment: Thank you for commenting but I also understand that some smart people had removed the sqlite tag from the question. Both tags were included for a reason.

Answer (score -1):

you have pasted image. So, difficult for us to copy text and create scripts. You should share scripts while asking questions.

What is the issue with UNION please share. I think below query should work. But share your issue too with union.

```
SELECT Fruit Fruit_Veggie, Count count_Fruit, percent percent_Fruit, 0 Count_Veggie, 0 pecent_Veggie FROM A
UNION
SELECT veggie, 0, 0, count, percent from B
```

Comment: It's because of `tomato`. He wanted the row from `fruit` and `veggie` table shown side by side whereas with `union`, it will instead show two rows of `tomato`. Probably `union` become subquery then `group by`?

Comment: Agreed. For trying I need data scripts and I am not going to create scripts myself for this question.